# Recursion when generating 404 errors

Tags: django, django-views, http-status-code-404, middleware

I use standard pagination from Django. The bottom line is that need to generate a 404 error when there are no posts on the page. That is, in the `blog` section there are only two pages of posts. It is necessary that when opening the page `blog/3/` error `404` falls. Here is the code I got from the previous developer.

**view**

```
ITEMS_ON_PAGE = 10


class BlogViewMixin(ListView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'articles'
    category = None

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = super(BlogViewMixin, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)

        if (self.kwargs.get('page')) == '1':
            raise Http404

        page = self.kwargs.get('page', 1)
        category = self.kwargs.get('category', None)

        if category:
            category = get_object_or_404(Category, url=category)
            queryset = queryset.filter(category=category)
            self.category = category

        paginator = Paginator(queryset, ITEMS_ON_PAGE)

        try:
            queryset = paginator.page(page)
        except EmptyPage:
            queryset = []

        #Here I tried to raise 404

        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogViewMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['current_page'] = self.kwargs.get('page', None)
        if context['current_page']:
            context['current_page'] = int(context['current_page'])

        context['current_category'] = self.category
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.exclude(is_green_button=True)
        context['marked_category'] = Category.objects.filter(is_green_button=True).first()
        context['SITE_URL'] = settings.SITE_URL
        context['pages'] = Page.objects.filter(show_on_main_menu=True, is_draft=False).order_by('order')

        return context


class BlogView(BlogViewMixin):
    template_name = 'blog/index.html'
```

Trying to throw an error in

```
if not queryset:
    raise Http404
```

but goes into recursion. I rewrote the `middleware` for processing 404. Maybe the reason is in it.

**middleware**

```
import requests, re
​
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import resolve, Resolver404
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponsePermanentRedirect
​
​
class RedirectMiddleware(object):
    response_redirect_class = HttpResponsePermanentRedirect
​
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
​
    def __call__(self, request):
​
        response = self.get_response(request)
​
        path = re.sub("/+", "/", request.path)
​
        if response.status_code == 404:
            if not path.endswith('/'):
                request.path = path
            else:
                request.path = path[:-1]
            try:
                full_path = request.get_full_path(force_append_slash=True) # add the slash, keeping query parameters
                r = resolve(full_path)
                response = r.func(request, args=r.args, kwargs=r.kwargs)
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    return redirect(full_path)
            except:
                if requests.get(request.build_absolute_uri() + '/').status_code == 200:
                    return redirect(full_path)
                pass  # this will fall through to `return response`
​
        # Add the Content-Length header to non-streaming responses if not
        # already set.
        if not response.streaming and not response.has_header('Content-Length'):
            response['Content-Length'] = str(len(response.content))
        return response
```

**blog/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', BlogView.as_view(), name='blog'),
    url(r'^(?P<page>\d+)/$', BlogView.as_view(), name='blog'),

    url(r'^category/(?P<category>[-\w]+)/$', CategoryView.as_view(), name='blog-category'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category>[-\w]+)/(?P<page>\d+)/$', CategoryView.as_view(), name='blog-category'),

    url(r'^(?P<article>[-\w]+)/$', ArticleView.as_view(), name='blog-article'),
]
```

Comment: Just set `allow_empty = False` as a class attribute in your `ListView` subclass. All the rest is not necessary.

Comment: I setted it, but it did not work. The page `blog/3/` opened and it had a list of all the entries. I had to build a crutch.

Comment: what's the url pattern you use for this? is `page` in the url? usually it's in the query parameters (?page=3)

Comment: I'm use `/blog/3/`

Comment: show us urls.py?

Comment: Of course. Updated code.

Comment: When you set `allow_empty = False` you should also remove the entire `get_queryset()` method (at least not paginate there). Actually, it's wrong to override the pagination in the `get_queryset()` method, you need to do that in the `paginate_queryset()` method.

Comment: Use [this](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.list/ListView/) as reference, it's invaluable to figure out where to override methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198553/discussion-between-dirkgroten-and-pythoner).